# Import org.junit cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, junit

I have a class file beginning with the following in Eclipse:

```
package org.jsoup.parser;

import org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder;
```

However, Eclipse indicates an error saying that org.junit cannot be resolved. I have already modified the project properties to include jUnit 3 in the classpath, so wouldn't know what to do further.

Ideas?

EDIT: I have included jUnit 4 as suggested but to no avail...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `org.junit.Assert` you should include JUnit 4. JUnit 3 uses `junit.framework.*` packages.

Comment: It looks like you changed build path of project `b` but the class with error is in project `jsoup1`.